# Using web proxy with curl

Tags: php, http, curl, webproxy

I would like to use `curl` to make HTTP `POST` requests through a web proxy. I have an example without a proxy.

Is it possible to make a programmatic post to a web proxy using `curl` passing in my destination URL, and get the result?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just post request to url `https://zend2.com/ru/vip3.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fflnau.ru` `u` it's url for request by function `url_encode`.